# ArrayList with 2 fields into ORMLite android

Tags: android, arraylist, ormlite

I get JsonArray from web service and parse it with Gson to ArrayList of corresponding class. 
This is my class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "categories")
public class Category {
    public final static String CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME  = "title";
    @SerializedName("id")
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME)
    String title;

    // need for ORMlite
    public Category() {}

    public Category (int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    // getters/setters/toString methods here
}
```

In my Activity I parse it to the ArrayList:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Category>>() {}.getType();
List<Category> tasks = new ArrayList<Category>();
tasks = gson.fromJson(array.toString(), listType);
```

In result, I get ArrayList with my data and it saves correctly. Then, in my DatabaseHandler, which extends from OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper I use method for saving ArrayList in the database:

```
  public void saveCategories(List<Category> contacts) throws SQLException {
        Dao<Category, Integer> daoContact=this.getDao(Category.class);
        for (Category contact : contacts) {
            daoContact.create(contact);
        }
    }
```

But when I call this method with my ArrayList I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object {title=Non-categorized id=1}: INSERT INTO `categories` (`title` ,`id` ) VALUES (?,?)
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:124)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:363)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:306)
    at com.library.DatabaseHandler.saveCategories(DatabaseHandler.java:148)
    at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:104)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: inserting to database failed: INSERT INTO `categories` (`title` ,`id` ) VALUES (?,?)
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:134)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:89)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:122)
    ... 16 more
```

Tell me please, how I should to orginize correct data saving in classes and database.

Comment: On the surface this looks fine.  Can you edit your post and add the entire error message and exception?

Comment: There should be an exception cause section below that.  Can you post the full exception?

Comment: you're right..Fixed it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your exception is trying to tell you, the error is happening because Sqlite is throwing the exception: `"error code 19: constraint failed"`.  Here's the limited documentation around [Sqlite error codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html):

So there is some constraint that you have hit.  If you used [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to generate your schema then the only thing I can think of is that you are trying to insert a row that has a duplicate ID field.

**Edit:**

After going back and forth, it turns out that there were already objects in the database with the same ids.  By querying for the ids *before* doing the `create(...)` you can then make a decision about calling `update(...)` or `create(...)`.

When I do this however, I get a better exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object
    com.j256.ormlite.db.SqliteConnectTest$IdConstraint@7971f189:
    INSERT INTO `idconstraint` (`id` ,`stuff` ) VALUES (?,?)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object
    com.j256.ormlite.db.SqliteConnectTest$IdConstraint@7971f189:
    INSERT INTO `idconstraint` (`id` ,`stuff` ) VALUES (?,?)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to
    constraint violation (PRIMARY KEY must be unique)
```

Are you sure you are using an up-to-date version of the Xerial Sqlite driver?  I'm using version 3.6.20.

Comment: yes, it's possible...but I can't understand why does it happens...(

Comment: Do you have some test data in the database already that has not been cleared out?  Maybe you need to `dao.queryById(...)` first on each of the objects to make sure it doesn't already exist in the database before you create it @user1512250?

Comment: I assume that means your handler is `null`?  Sounds like your wiring is not correct somehow @user1512250.

Comment: I tried like you say and I can read all the objects with Log.i("DAO",categoryDao.queryForId(3).toString());                       So objects are in database and I can get them with the Dao.

Comment: Good.  So it looks like the problem was that you were trying to `create(...)` objects that were already in the database?

Comment: Thank you, objects were in the database and I tried to add them once more...!!!!!thank you!

Comment: But what is solution to prevent that type of error when upsync and downsync performing with live database

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I added elements twice to the database. Thanks to [Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray)